# sorting numbers

Tags: matlab, sorting, numbers, sequence, combinations

How to generate a combination of 5 elements out of 8 elements where the final list should have only the combination of 5 elements which are two or more elements different from each other? 
I started replacing the elements with numbers from 1-8 and generated the initial list using:

```
x = 1:8;
v = permn(x,5);
```

The initial list consists 8^5 numbers. e. g. 11111,11112,11113.....88888.

If I take the starting seed as 11111, the sorted numbers can be like, 11122, 11123 and so on. Because these numbers are atleast two element difference with 11111. But then from this second list, both 11122 and 11123 can't go to the next list because they have only one element difference.
The final list should have all these unique set of elements which has atleast two or more element difference with each other.
Can someone please help me to implement the condition?

Comment: Assume that you have numbers 11111 and 11112, which one should be removed?

Comment: @rahnema1 If you start sorting based on 11111, then 11112 is already eliminated because it has only one element difference from 11111. you will get numbers like 11122, 11123, 11124....11132,11133,11134....and so on. The next list should be based on 11122 i.e 11133, 11143, 11153...next list should be based on 11133 i.e. 11144, 11154, 11164 and so on. The final list should have 11111, 11122, 11133, 11144...and so on. Final set of elements should have two or more element difference.

Comment: What about 11123 and 23111? Are they unique?

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes they are.  The sequences are different so both of them will be counted as two different elements.

Comment: "They are unique" and at the same time "both of them will be counted as two different elements"?!!

Comment: @rahnema1: Sorry, I meant both of them will make to the list because they satisfy the criteria of being different by two elements. The positions are important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterative solution have and order `o(n^2)` with `n=size(v,1)`:

```
m=1
while m < size(v,1)
    part2 = v(m+1:end, :);
    %compare each row with the following rows e.g. part2.
    u = bsxfun(@ne, v(m,:), part2);
    %check if number of different elements greater than 1
    s = sum(u,2) > 1;
    %extract those rows and append to the current rows
    v= [v(1:m,:); part2(s,:)];
    m = m + 1;
end
```

The final `v` will have unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bubble sort with inner and outer loop, compare elements from inner loop and outer loop based on rank (*rank = 1 if two or more elements differ*) thereafter swap elements if rank <> 0.

**Pseudo Code**

```
For I= 0 to (N-1)
    For J= I+1 to N
       If Rank(Array(I), Array(J)) <> 0 Then
           Swap(Array(I), Array(J))
       End
    End
End
```